# How to remove specific symbol in text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove specific text from incoming value

```
changeable:# this can be changeable
global:# this is global
manager:# this is manager
```

what I want:

```
this can be changeable
this is global
this is manager
```

How can I remove it also the space after `#`

Comment: It sounds like you need a "javascript regular expression". Have you tried searching for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace method

- `^` - Start of string
- `[^#]*` - Match anything except `#` zero or more time
- `#` - Match `#`
- `\s*` - Match space character zero or more time

```js
let strArr = [`changeable:# this can be changeable`, `global:# this is global`, `manager:# this is manager`]

let textModifier = (str) => {
  console.log(str.replace(/^[^#]*#\s*/, ''))
}

strArr.forEach(textModifier)
```

Comment: good it's work but can i do it with out [ ] like let strArr = 'changeable:# this can be changeable' cause it come one by one not as a list

Comment: Yes you can `[]` was just for demo, `str.replace(/^[^#]*#\s*/, '')` all you need :)

Comment: so it will look like let textModifier = (str) => {
                                console.log(str.replace(/^[^#]*#\s*/, ''));
                            }

                            html.data.forEach(textModifier);

Comment: forEach is required when you have an list/ and you want to loop over it

Comment: i get them from html so what should i do <div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    changeable:# this can be changeable</div>

Comment: thanks it will be like      var text = data.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/ig, " ");
                                console.log(text);
                                var cleartext= text.replace(/^[^#]*#\s*/, '')
                            console.log(cleartext);